# Simplify Element Class Toggling

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this line of code in javascript to select multiple classes to toggle dark mode theme:

```
let header = document.querySelector('header'),
    mobile = document.querySelector('.mobile'),
    themeButton = document.querySelector('.theme'),
    navbar = document.querySelector('.navbar'),
    videoContainer = document.querySelector('.video-container'),

themeButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  header.classList.toggle('dark-mode');
  mobile.classList.toggle('dark-mode');
  navbar.classList.toggle('dark-mode');
  videoContainer.classList.toggle('dark-mode');
});
```

can I simplifiy it so it doesnt take too long? This is my github links if you're interested: [text](https://github.com/halex-panama/youtube-clone)

Comment: "*so it doesnt take too long*" - are you looking for faster code or just for shorter code?

Comment: I mean sorter code

Comment: I can't think of a meaningful case where one needs to apply theme-specific styling by setting the theme-specific class-name separately to different elements. In my opinion the class-name of any theme has to be set/changed at the document-element, hence the `<html>` tag as for HTML. And for the OP's use case, I belief doing the toggling like ... `document.documentElement.classList.toggle('dark-mode');` ... is all what's needed since the theme-specific styling anyhow should be done by theme-specifc CSS rules like ... `:root.dark-mode .navbar { ... } :root.dark-mode .video-container { ... }`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution should be you need to add the `dark-mode` to the parent element.

https://dev.to/phuchieu/dark-theme-with-css-variable-1fjo

Here is the useful URL you can learn from.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you set class `theme-dark` to `body` element and use CSS veriables for colors:

```css
.theme-dark{
  --body-bg:#333;
  --color:#aaa;
  --input-bg: #555;
}
body{
  background-color: var(--body-bg);
  color: var(--color);
}

input, button{
  color: var(--color);
  background-color: var(--input-bg);
}
```

```html
<input><button onclick="document.body.classList.toggle('theme-dark')">Toggle dark theme</button>
```